# Bigquery delete rows that are present in another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, bigquery-udf

I want to delete all the rows from table t1 which are present in table t2.

```
table_1 is as follows

a   b   c
1   4   3
3   334 3
5   4   5
6   5   4
4   85  3
7   332 54
8   46  6
45  42  5
7   576 6
```

and table 2 is as follows

```
a   b   c
7   332 54
3   334 3
7   576 6
```

as mentioned I would like to delete all the rows from table t1 which are present in table t2.

So I used the code

```
DELETE `projectname.datasetname.table1` t
WHERE t IN (SELECT * from `projectname.datasetname.table2`)
```

but it doesn't work, what would be the ideal solution here?
My desired result is

```
a   b   c
1   4   3
5   4   5
6   5   4
4   85  3
8   46  6
45  42  5
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't help"?  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: Table_1 has 10 rows and table_2 has 3 rows , the same 3 rows from Table_2 is available in Table_1..I would like to delete those 3 rows from Table_1 so that I have Table_1 with 7 rows now:  doesn't help means the code didn't worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to look at the entire record, you can use:

```
DELETE `projectname.datasetname.table1` t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM `projectname.datasetname.table2` t2
              WHERE TO_JSON_STRING(t2) = TO_JSON_STRING(t)
             );
```

However, normally a comparison of a simple id column of some sort is usually sufficient for such comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Use below

```
DELETE `projectname.datasetname.table1` t
WHERE TO_JSON_STRING(t) IN (SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) from `projectname.datasetname.table2` t);
```